# UICollectionview item number

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have `UIcollectionview` with sections. In `cellForItemAtIndexPath` i can see `indexPath.section` and `indexPath.item`. How can i know number of the item from the very beginning of the first section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in method. But you can add the number of items of all previous
sections to the item number within the current section:

```
NSInteger num = indexPath.item;
for (NSInteger section = 0; section < indexPath.section; section++) {
    num += [collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section];
}
```

But perhaps you should also check if you really need this. For example, if the reason is
that your data source is a flat array then you might consider to rearrange the data source,
reflecting the two-level sections/items structure.

Answer (score 0):

You need the cell at indexPath (0,0), so try:

```
NSIndexPath * indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem: 0 inSection: 0];
```

and then use `cellForItemAtIndexPath` as before

Answer (score -1):

You might be looking for `indexPath.row`.

Comment: indexPath.row and indexPath.item are the same.

Comment: They are not the same ;) the lead to the same result (at least I did not experience any difference) but originally indexPath.row was used for UITableViews and .item was introduced with and used for UICollectionViews (see [here for details](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html)